# Laravel Controllers: Extracting Code/Logic Into Trait

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, traits, dry

I am creating some simple forum and this is my case:

- I have two models: `Thread` and `Post`;
- `Thread` has only `title` attribute, `Post` has only `body` attribute;
- When a user wants to create (start) a new Thread - he will have to submit one form that contains two fields:  *title* (thread title) and *body* (that will be the first post).

So, when someone creates a new thread, he also creates the first post of that thread.

This form (with *title* and *body*  fields) for starting a new thread is submitted to `ThreadsController@store` where I do the following:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Store a newly created thread in storage.
    $thread = new Thread();
    $thread->title = $request->title;
    $thread = \Auth::user()->threads()->save($thread);

    // Store a newly post in storage.
    $post = new Post();
    $post->body = $request->body;
    $post->thread_id = $thread->id;
    \Auth::user()->posts()->save($post);

    return back();
}
```

But, when someone replies (creates a new post within the thread) - he will have to submit a form that only contains *body* field, and that will be submitted to `PostsController@store`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Store a newly post in storage.
    $post = new Post();
    $post->body = $request->body;
    $post->thread_id = $thread->id;
    \Auth::user()->posts()->save($post);

    return back();
}
```

As you can see - these two controllers are using the same code for storing a newly post in storage:

```
// Store a newly post in storage.
$post = new Post();
$post->body = $request->body;
$post->thread_id = $thread->id;
\Auth::user()->posts()->save($post);
```

Is it good to move this code into a Trait? For example, in `app/http` I would create `traits` directory in which I would put `PostsControllerTrait`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Traits;

use App\Post;
use App\Thread;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

trait PostsControllerTrait
{
    /**
     * Store a newly created post in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param Thread $thread
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function storePost(Request $request, Thread $thread)
    {
        $post = new Post();
        $post->body = $request->body;
        $post->thread_id = $thread->id;
        \Auth::user()->posts()->save($post);
    }
}
```

As for the name **PostsControllerTrait** - the reason I have *"Controller"* in the name is because this trait will be used only in controllers. For me, **PostsTrait** looks like something related to Eloquent Models.

Finally, what do you suggest - where to create`traits` directory: in `app/http`or just in `app`? Or is it a matter of preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages
>   such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single
>   inheritance by enabling a developer to **reuse sets of methods freely in
>   several independent classes living in different class hierarchies**. The
>   semantics of the combination of Traits and classes is defined in a way
>   which reduces complexity, and avoids the typical problems associated
>   with multiple inheritance and Mixins.

You are creating a reuse code, and mostly the reuse code you created will not be used in other independent classes. Therefore, you can put your reuse code to the `Post` Model.

```
class Post extends Model {
    ...

    public function storePost(User $user, Thread $thread, $body) {
        $this->body = $body;
        $this->thread_id = $thread->id;
        $user->posts()->save($this);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It will be much simpler if you use Laravel model relationship (i.e one to many relationship [laravel one to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many%20%22One%20to%20many%20relationship%22))) to store post to a thread.

Define the relationship between thread and post as a thread have many posts. Then simply save $thread->posts()->save($post);